# Javascript href and span tag in anchor?

Tags: javascript

I have this markup,

```
<a href="http://www.example.com">Hiya<span class="delete">Delete</span></a>
```

And my js,

```
$('.delete').click(function() {
    window.location = 'http://www.example.com/example';
});
```

My problem the anchor tag always win presedence over my javascript `window.location` how can I overcome this?

Thanks

Comment: Why place it inside an `<a>` tag if you dont want that functionality. Why not `<a href="http://www.example.com">Hiya</a><span class="delete">Delete</span>`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to return false from the `click()` event to prevent the default behaviour:

```
$('.delete').click(function(e) {
    e.stopPropagation();
    window.location = 'http://www.example.com/example';
    return false;
});
```

Comment: This doesn't work as it is in its own span tag and not the anchor tag!

Comment: Add `e.stopPropagation()` to stop the event bubbling up to the `<a>`. I have edited my answer for you.

Comment: Thanks, will have to look up on that it works though thanks!!

Comment: Thanks. If it helped, would you mind accepting the answer? :)

Comment: Had to wait there is a time limit now

Answer (score 1):

Use `return false;`

```
$('.delete').click(function() {
    window.location = 'http://www.example.com/example';
return false;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried with:

```
$('.delete').click(function(ev) {
  ev.preventDefault()
  window.location = 'http://www.example.com/example';
});
```

Not sure, though, since "span" is not a clickable tag.

Comment: It's clickable, it just doesn't have a default action to prevent. `ev.stopPropagation();` should work though, to stop the click bubbling up to the anchor element.

Answer (score 0):

You might be looking for http://api.jquery.com/event.stopPropagation/

```
$(".delete").click(function(event){
  event.stopPropagation();
  // do something
});
```